# What is the meaning of double nested type qualifiers on powershell assignments?

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell statement that I am trying to understand, in particular what type does it make its variable.

```
[double] [boolean] $x = 12.5
$x
$x.GetType()
$x += .5
```

The results of the 3 uses of $x are:

```
1
Double
1
```

So, does it mean that $x always converts its values to a Boolean but then returns it as a Double?

Is there a page that documents what this should do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, does it mean that `$x` always converts its values to a Boolean but then returns it as a Double

Sort of, yes. `12.5` (and any subsequent value assigned to the variable) is converted to the boolean value `$true`, and then `$true` is converted to the numerical value `1.0`.

To understand why, I think it might be useful to review how variable typing works in PowerShell.

From the [`about_Variables` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables):

> ### Types of variables
>
> You can store **any type of object in a variable**, including integers, strings, arrays, and hash tables. And, objects that represent processes, services, event logs, and computers.
>
> PowerShell **variables are loosely typed**, which means that they aren't limited to a particular type of object. A single variable can even contain a collection, or array, of different types of objects at the same time.
>
> The data type of a variable is determined by the .NET types **of the values of the variable**.

(*emphasis added*)

That is:

- Variables in PowerShell are NOT intrisically typed
- The resulting type of a variable expression depends entirely on the *value* stored

So what does PowerShell provide us with to control the type of the value assigned to a variable? From the same section of the help topic above:

> You can use a type attribute and cast notation to ensure that a variable can contain only specific object types or objects that can be converted to that type. **If you try to assign a value of another type, PowerShell tries to convert the value to its type**. If the type can't be converted, the assignment statement fails.
>
> To use cast notation, enter a type name, enclosed in brackets, before the variable name (on the left side of the assignment statement). The following example creates a `$number` variable that can contain only integers, [...]
>
> ```
> [int]$number = 8
> $number = "12345"  # The string is converted to an integer.
> $number = "Hello"
> # ArgumentTransformationMetadataException thrown
> ```

So PowerShell doesn't actually type the variable itself, but it adds something to it that makes it attempt a type conversion on assignment - let's have a look at this "something" it adds.

Start by assigning a value of the desired type to a variable, without attempting any left-hand side cast:

```bsh
PS ~> $aBool = $true
PS ~> $aBool -is [bool]
True
PS ~> Get-Variable -Name aBool |Format-List

Name          : aBool
Description   :
Value         : True
Visibility    : Public
Module        :
ModuleName    :
Options       : None
Attributes    : {}
```

Notice that the (string representation of the) value, `True`, looks correct, but there's no real indication of its type - exactly as we'd expect from a truly "loosely-typed" variable.

Now let's do the same thing, but with the cast notation used above:

```
PS ~> [bool]$aBool = 123 # Let's assign a non-[bool] value to a variable with a left-hand cast
PS ~> $aBool -is [bool]  # resulting value is still [bool], as expected
True
PS ~> Get-Variable -Name aBool |Format-List

Name          : aBool
Description   :
Value         : True
Visibility    : Public
Module        :
ModuleName    :
Options       : None
Attributes    : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}

PS ~> (Get-Variable -Name aBool).Attributes |Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute

Name                            MemberType Definition
----                            ---------- ----------
Equals                          Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode                     Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                         Method     type GetType()
IsDefaultAttribute              Method     bool IsDefaultAttribute()
Match                           Method     bool Match(System.Object obj)
ToString                        Method     string ToString()
Transform                       Method     System.Object Transform(System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, System.Object inputData)
TransformNullOptionalParameters Property   bool TransformNullOptionalParameters {get;}
TypeId                          Property   System.Object TypeId {get;}
```

Aha! The variable still doesn't have a type, but it now carries an `ArgumentTypeConverter` attribute with it.

The type converter attribute itself isn't strongly-typed either, but it *will* always either return a value of the type specified in a left-hand cast (or throw a conversion error):

```bsh
PS ~> $typeConverter = (Get-Variable aBool).Attributes[0]
PS ~> $typeConverter.Transform($ExecutionContext, 123)
True
PS ~> $typeConverter.Transform($ExecutionContext, '')
False
```

So when you write an assignment statement with multiple type casts on the left-hand side of the expression, PowerShell simply stores the whole list as individual type converter attributes:

```bsh
PS ~> [double][bool]$aDoubleBool = 123
PS ~> (Get-Variable aDoubleBool).Attributes

TransformNullOptionalParameters TypeId
------------------------------- ------
                           True System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute
                           True System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute
```

We can't really tell from the output, but the first one is the type converter generated from `[bool]`, the last one is for `[double]` - that is, PowerShell *chains* them, from right-most to left-most.

We can replicate this behavior by manually chaining the conversions:

```bsh
PS ~> 
>> (Get-Variable aDoubleBool).Attributes |%{
>>   $value = $_.Transform($ExecutionContext, $value)
>> }

PS ~> $value -is [double]
True
PS ~> $value
1
```

So you can add and subtract as many decimal values as you want, the assigned value will *always* be `0.0` or `1.0` due to the `[bool]`->`[double]` conversion :)